# jQuery Help for Simple Problem

Tags: jquery

I wrote a custom dropdown menu, the issue is that if you hover over it to quick it starts going up and down frantically. Here is an example: http://www.norrispenrose.com/

Here is my jQuery Code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ // menu system
      jQuery('#mainMenu li').hover(function() {
              jQuery(this).corner('5px');
          });

      jQuery('#mainMenu li').hover(function() {
         if(jQuery(this).children().is('ul'))
          {
              jQuery(this).uncorner();
              jQuery(this).corner('top 5px');
              jQuery('ul', this).slideDown('fast');
              jQuery('ul', this).uncorner();
              jQuery('ul', this).corner('tr br bl 5px');
              jQuery(this).addClass('dropHover');
          }
          else
          {
      //Do nothing
      }

      }, function() {
          jQuery('ul', this).slideUp('fast');
          jQuery(this).delay(200).queue(function () {
              jQuery(this).removeClass('dropHover');
              jQuery(this).dequeue();
          });
          jQuery(this).uncorner();

      }); 
  });
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you improve on the title of this question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop jquery queuing events.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594175/stop-jquery-queuing-events)

Comment: What should I change the title to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before your `slideUp` and `slideDown` use the jQuery `stop()` method ([**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)) to clear the animation queue.  For example from your code:

```
jQuery('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, I knew it was something simple just didn't know what!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [HoverIntent plug-in](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).  That should solve your problem.